# How to find R,G,B, H, S, V value

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, hsv

I have a figure of paddy's leaf. I want to extract only paddy's leaf to R, G, B, H, S, V value. I have done to separate background and object. But I haven't been able to extract the value of color space. Can you help me? Thank you before.

this is my code:

```
rmat=Im(:,:,1)
gmat=Im(:,:,2);
bmat=Im(:,:,3);


subplot(2,2,1), imshow(rmat);
title('Red Plane');
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(gmat);
title('Green Plane');
subplot(2,2,3), imshow(bmat);
title('Blue Plane');
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(I);
title('Original Image');


%%levelr = 0.63;
levelg = 0.5;
levelb = 0.4;

i1=im2bw(rmat,levelr);
i2=im2bw(gmat,levelg);
i3=im2bw(bmat,levelb);
Isum = (i1&i2&i3);
```

and I want to know example: R= 60 B= 85 G=125

I am using MATLAB.

[image: Paddy leaf]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please try and improve it by saying what you tried, by showing your code, by saying how you expect the answer to look - will it be one word, or a CSV or a new image? Also mention your OS and tools.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What do you mean by *"I want to know R=60, B=85, G=125"*? If R=60, you already know R is 60. What's the question please?

Comment: It is just example, i wanna know average of R, G, B value of paddy's leaf not all of picture.

Comment: If you want to know average of RGB, why does your question title talk about HSV? You need to segment the image if you only want information about the leaf - have you done that yet?

Comment: I've segmented the image, but I have not been able to get the information about r, g, b, h, s, v value of the leaf. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Im` is your run-of-the-mill image, it will likely be in RGB. Thus,

```
rgb = Im(x,y,:)
```

will be a 3-element vector containing the RGB values of the pixel at `(x,y)`.

Next, use the [`rgb2hsv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) function to convert that triplet to an HSV triplet:

```
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgb)
```

You can also convert the whole image to HSV with that function in you want.

Comment: how to know average of RGB value just a paddy's leaf, not all the picture?